# What is the purpose of being able to call to_i on an Integer?

Tags: ruby, integer

Ruby allows converting between bases using Integer.to_s(base) and String.to_i(base).

I was hoping to convert a binary integer to a decimal integer, using Integer.to_i(base) but that doesn't work apparently

```
100.to_i(2)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

However, running

```
Integer.respond_to? :to_i
```

Gives a true value. Why is this so? What's a simpler way to convert between integers of different bases?

Comment: Show your code that causes the error.

Comment: I don't really understand your question, show your code.

Comment: I mean as in 100.to_i works but 100.to_i(2) won't work

Comment: How do you expect 100.to_i(2) to work?

Comment: I expected it to give me 4, like "100".to_i(2) works

Comment: @Coolshanth these are totally different numbers, `100` isn't equal to `4`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is because [`Integer#to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Integer.html#method-i-to_i) takes 0 argument, not 1.

To get the value of `100` in binary, use binary literal `0b100`:

```
0b100
# => 4
```

or convert it to a string first:

```
100.to_s.to_i(2)
# => 4
```

Comment: BTW `100` is not really binary `4`, it's `100`: `100 + 100 #=> 200`.

Comment: @MarekLipka I know `100` is a decimal number. OP is trying to *convert a binary integer to a decimal integer*, in my understanding, this is what he wants. Or perhaps I misunderstood.

Comment: I think you understood it correctly, but it's worth noting that if OP has `100` integer which is supposed to be binary `4`, he's doing something wrong.

Answer (score 5):

An integer is already in all bases at the same time. The base(something) representation only makes sense for a string. An integer is just a value and 10<sub>(10)</sub> is the same as 1010<sub>(2)</sub>.

Answer (score 5):

To answer just the title of your question:

> What is the purpose of being able to call to_i on an Integer?

It is provided mainly so that methods which require an Integer can accept `String`s, `Float`s and other types and *coerce* then to the required form, without needing to explicitly detect the class.

```
def method_that_needs_int( param )
  n = param.to_i
  # . . . whatever we want to do with n
end
```

`Integer#to_i` is essentially a no-op, but it can make your code simpler just by existing for cases like this.

Answer (score -1):

From the ruby-doc.org

> to_i → integer
>
> As int is already an Integer, all these methods simply return the
> receiver.
> Synonyms are to_int, floor, ceil, truncate.

Source code of the method

```
static VALUE
int_to_i(VALUE num)
{
    return num;
}
```

So there isn't any purpose.